# Goto to VLA scope

Tags: c

Is this allowed?

```
goto inside;
{
inside:
int a[n];
}
```

> A goto statement shall not jump from outside the scope of an
>   identifier having a variably modified type to inside the scope of that
>   identifier.

What about the inverse?

```
{
goto outside;
int a[n];
}
outside: ;
```

and

```
{
int a[n];
goto outside;
}
outside: ;
```

Are they the same thing?

Comment: your quote seems to answer your question

Comment: So you mean first code OK , second code OK third code NO and fourth code: OK;

Comment: 1. OK, 2. OK, 3. OK, 4. OK  . part 4 is a completely separate question to the rest, you should have posted as a different question

Comment: for the last part I am not sure if it is an important question that's why I included it inside this one it is like a check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is not allowed, but the reason is that you can't apply a label to a declaration.

The label comes before the scope of the VLA, and if there were executable code (formally, a *statement*; even an empty one would do) to label, then you'd be OK:

```
goto inside;
{
    inside:;
    int a[n];   // Scope of a starts here!
}
```

Both the `goto outside` fragments are fine.

---

There was a discussion about the scope of identifiers in comments, and when the array `a[n]` comes into scope.
The standards (both C99 and C11 — in the same section number) say:

> #### 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers
>
> ¶7 Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of
> the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that
> begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. Any
> other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.

It was in §6.1.2.1 in the C90 standard, but the wording was the same.

Comment: This is what I thought too the scope of VLA starts from the declaration and not from starting of block.

Answer (score 3):

Using `goto` to exit a scope that contains a VLA is perfectly fine. It's no different than exiting that scope using `return` or `break`.

The issue with using `goto` to enter a scope with a VLA is that a VLA declaration is treated as if it contains some code which calls [`alloca()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) to reserve stack space for the array. If you use `goto` to skip the declaration, you've also skipped that `alloca()` call, so there may not be any space reserved for the array.

Note that, `alloca()` aside, this isn't much different from skipping over a variable initialization (e.g, `int n = 1`). VLAs just behave as though they *always* have an initializer.